# Custom dynamic number format vba

Tags: vba, numbers, format

I am trying to format a range to a custom format. I need the numbers in the concerned cells to look like the following: `2 000 kg/h.`

In excel, I can go to the custom format and input # ##0" kg/h" and it works fine. In VBA the number format has to be written between the quotation marks and so we cannot put quotation marks inside it. Additionally, the " kg/h" part needs to be a string variable.

How can I implement this using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

To include quotes inside a string, use two quotes.

```
Debug.Print "This "" is a quote"
This " is a quote
```

Or you can use Chr() function. Chr(34) returns a double quote.

```
Dim units As String

units = "kg/h"

ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "# ##0" & Space(1) & Chr$(34) & units & Chr$(34)
```

That may be a little easier to read than

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "# ##0" & Space(1) & """" & units & """"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dick. Worked like a charm with the chr(34).